# Write over xml root, but keep header comment

Tags: python, python-3.x, xml, lxml

I have a script set up to use parse from lxml library in Python to read in xml files and provided some logic to remove a specified attribute. I would like write over the xml elements but keep a header comment.

Example.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Original Header
Some more info -->
<Foo Name = "Bar" Pet = "Able">
  <Foo2 Name = "Bar2" />
  <Foo3 Name = "Bar3" />
</Foo>
```

I would like to write back into the xml file after going through the processing logic such that the Example.xml would look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Original Header
Some more info -->
<Foo Name = "Bar">
  <Foo2 Name = "Bar2" />
  <Foo3 Name = "Bar3" />
</Foo>
```

The removing of the attribute is something I have already figured out. Writing back into the same xml  file and preserving the header is what I can't think of a solution to. Worst case scenario is I make an output folder and manually do a BeyondCompare with the files, but I would like to automate this completely.

Comment: https://poopcode.com/python-code-snippet-how-to-read-comment-before-the-root-element-of-xml/

Answer (score 0):

You can do it very easily with `BeautifulSoup` using the `lxml` parser. First, open the file for reading, parse the contents using `BeautifulSoup`, make changes as required then open the file for writing and write to the file.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


with open('./Example.xml', 'r') as f:
    xml = f.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(xml, 'lxml-xml')
foo = soup.find('Foo')
del foo['Pet']
with open('./Example.xml', 'w') as f:
    f.write(soup.prettify())
```

It can be written more concisely as:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


with open('./Example.xml', 'r') as f:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(f.read(), 'xml')
del soup.find('Foo')['Pet']
with open('./Example.xml', 'w') as f:
    f.write(soup.prettify())
```

Comment: I'd also assume you could use soup.find('Foo2')['OtherAttribute'] to remove an attribute from a child element as well?

Comment: Yes, BeautifulSoup is very powerful you can add, remove or update any element, attribute, comment or text. See the documentation at https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/